# Why does Remix / Metamask sometimes fail to publish a contract

Tags: remix, metamask, rinkeby

When I paste my contract into Remix and try to `Create` it, I occasionally get:

`callback contain no result Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

If I click `create` a few more times, it usually works and the Metamask popup appears.

Then, sometimes the transaction will succeed, but sometimes Metamask will give me the same error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

But sometimes it works. All with the same code pasted into the Remix window. What could be going wrong? I'm on Rinkeby.

It always works when using the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the error that MetaMask reports when it gets HTML instead of JSON from its backend provider.

AKA when Infura has a 405 (overwhelmed) error. This can happen when the Infura network has a sudden and surprising surge of traffic.